# Is it possible to read Python GObject Introspection API documentation offline using already installed packages and files?

Tags: 20.04, python, python3, gtk3, documentation

On my Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS system I see many packages named *gir1.2...*.
For example I want to develop some new functionality on Python using `gir1.2-gtk-3.0` and `gir1.2-caja-2.0`.
Such packages usually have only `*.typelib` files and do not provide any HTML documentation.

I do not see their documentation in DevHelp, Yelp and DocHelp.

With reading of which offline installed documentation should I start?

Comment: Going by [the packaging code](https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/pygobject/-/tree/debian/master/debian), `python-pygobject`'s documentation isn't packaged. Probably an ovnersight, maybe worth filing a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is possible by visiting special site at https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/ and finding needed Python GObject Gir/Typelib docs here.

The above special site is built using special [*pgi-docgen* utility](https://github.com/pygobject/pgi-docgen). It uses Docker under the hood.
I this project to ease the process of local documentation creation.

To build local documentation

- for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and newer (based on Debian Bullseye) -

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/N0rbert/pgi-docgen
  cd pgi-docgen
  ./docker-build.sh
  ```
- for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (based on Debian Buster) -

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/N0rbert/pgi-docgen -b debian-buster
  cd pgi-docgen
  ./docker-build.sh
  ```

Local documentation will be build in *_docs/_build* folder. Maybe browsed using any web-browser.